# Container of a site with youtube videos goes left - wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, youtube

I created a site on my blog where I'm putting yt videos. Unfortunately the container of this site goes left and I have no idea why. It doesn't happen to any other site of the blog. 
I'm using Virtue theme - https://www.kadencethemes.com/product/virtue-free-theme/

Here's the link to the site I have problem with: http://mlodziez-wks.slask.pl/multimedia/wideo/

I would be more than thankful for help.

Comment: It is caused by the 'wideo' class that is added to the body element.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you added that CSS in your stylesheet

```
.wideo {
    width: 300px;
    heignt: 169px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Which class is getting called in your "body" tag. And you are forcing your body to stay in 300px width only. Therefore you need to remove it or replace it with

```
.wideo {
    width: 100%;
    heignt: 169px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have the CSS class `wideo` iny our body element, that is adding the following CSS style to it:

```
width: 300px;
heignt: 169px;
display: inline-block;
```

You need to remove this class from the body, it is defined outside a CSS file, so it must be added over some theme customisation or similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Set your css to

```
.wideo {
width:100%;
height: 169px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

This will solve your problem.